# Declined PhD offer, but now I regret it

Tags: phd, rejection

Last summer, I was offered a Ph.D. position at a famous University, but unfortunately, while initially I accepted it, then I had to reject it due to significant family circumstances that I explained to my potential supervisor and they understood (at least that's how I understood).

Until last December (2021) the position had not been filled by another candidate (curious about this), and the position re-advertised the same month.

I contacted the supervisor, if could I apply again for this position, and they told me that of course I can, once again.

Do you believe that I have possibilities to acquire again the position or the behaviour that I showed will play a significant factor to reject me?
I'm so anxious about this, because ever since I wanted such a position, and the time that came, life circumstances did not permit it.

I would appreciate any response!

Thank you!

Comment: A very similar question with similar idiosyncratic writing style has been asked. Have you already asked this question here?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Are you referring to [I rejected a PhD offer but now would like to accept it again](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176468/43873)?

Comment: @shoover That might have been it

Answer (score 15):

They've already told you you can apply, so of course you can apply. If they were going to reject you they'd presumably tell you not to apply to both save your time and theirs.

On the other hand, you'll need to compete against this year's prospective PhD students. Maybe a particularly outstanding student applied this year. There's no guarantee you'll be accepted.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Re-apply and see what happens.

> [will] the behaviour that I showed will play a significant factor to reject me? I'm so anxious about this

With respect - I believe this is more of the issue. Academia can be very anxiety-inducing (as many questions here on the site indicate). You need to think about ways to relieve stress, and deal with the fear of being categorized as inadequate, unworthy etc. - which, based on what you've told us, you really aren't!

See also:

[How to effectively deal with Imposter Syndrome and feelings of inadequacy: "I've somehow convinced everyone that I'm actually good at this"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11765/how-to-effectively-deal-with-imposter-syndrome-and-feelings-of-inadequacy-ive)